# Ansible tower - Run multiple playbooks at once

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-template, ansible-tower

I want to run multiple playbooks at once on ansible tower, How do I create job template for this? Job template is allowing me to select only one playbook at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to

- either create a separate playbook with a a list of playbooks imported by using [`import_playbook` to Import a playbook](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_playbook_module.html)
- or use  [Workflow Job Templates](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/workflow_templates.html) which "*... links together a sequence of disparate resources ...*" like [Job Templates](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/job_templates.html)

Answer (score 2):

Job template does not allow you to select multiple playbooks at a time.

You can try workflow template by creating multiple Job Templates each pointing to different playbooks and call them from a workflow template.